# How many functions g can be defined from set $A=\{0,1,...,2^n-1,2^n\}$ to set $B=\{0,...,n\}$ such that $g(2^x)=x$ for all $x \in B$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many functions g can be defined from set $A=\{0,1,...,2^n-1,2^n\}$ to set $B=\{0,...,n\}$ such that $g(2^x)=x$ for all $x \in B$?

---

CURRENT ATTEMPT

$A=\{0,1,...,2^n-1,2^n\}$

$B=\{0,...,n\}$

$g(2^x)=x$ for all $x$ in $B$

$g:A \rightarrow B$

let $g^n(x)=\frac{1}{\log_n(2)}\log_n(x)$

$\therefore g^n(2^x)= \frac{1}{\log_n(2)}log_n(2^x)=x$

which is true for all $x \in B$ and real $n$

Hence there are an infinite number of functions of the form $g^n(x)$ as $n$ varies continuously in the interval $(0, \infty)$.

I am not sure I have done the right thing so I wanted to see what the community thinks.

Comment: Any thoughts? looks like you have specified $n$ values, with no constraints at all on the other values.

Comment: If anything else fails, have you tried to write it down and count for small $n$?

Comment: I think you have mis-framed the question.  You seem to believe $n$ is a variable in the context of your solution.  You should think of this problem as "Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.  For each $n$, how many functions can be defined from $A = {}$..."  You should get a count of the number of such functions, represented as a function $f: \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, taking $n$ to the number of functions for that $n$.

Comment: Consider the $n=2$ case: how many functions $g : \{0,1,2,3,4\} \to \{0,1,2\}$ are there with $g(1) = 0$, $g(2) = 1$, and $g(4) = 2$? You should be able to list them all. Then generalize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have defined as $g^n(x)$ is in fact just $\log_2 x$, *independent of $n$*. That does not give infinitely many different functions. That also isn't a function from $A$ to $B$ because $g(0)$ is not defined (and some values in $A$ get mapped to a non-integer for $n\ge2$).

The given condition fixed $g(x)$ for $x\in\{2^k:k\in B\}=\{1,2,4,\dots,2^n\}$. For all the remaining numbers in $A$, $g(x)$ can be any of the $n+1$ numbers in $B$. Since there are $2^n-n$ elements in $A$ remaining, there are $(n+1)^{2^n-n}$ function satisfying the condition.

Comment: Slight correction: there are $2^n + 1 - n$ elements in $A$ remaining

Comment: No, $2^n-n$ is correct.